# Why do we use invalidat() twice?

Tags: android, invalidation

I read Hello Android book and i dont understand some parts of the PuzzleView class of the code.
invalidate() function is redrawing only a part of page,not redrawing all the page. this is true?

The following function, why do we use invalidate() twice? what is difference between these two?

```
private void select(int x, int y) {
    invalidate(selRect);
    selX = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), 8);
    selY = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), 8);
    getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
    invalidate(selRect);
}
```

Please help me .

Cheers

Comment: because the rect is changed in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

Because the rectangle being invalidated has potentially changed between the first call and second

View.invalidate(Rect dirty) will cause the area defined in dirty to be redrawn